# RStudio Freezing

Tags: r, rstudio

I have tried redownloading R and RStudio. I've also tried downloading it from Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome. When I run RStudio. It completely freezes and I cannot write edit anything and I also cannot close out RStudio without doing Ctrl+Alt+Delete to Task Manager to end task.

R (standalone) R x64 4.0.3 runs perfectly fine.

Does anyone else have this issue currently? This just started recently.

EDIT: I found a solution where if I open up a separate RStudio window while the one that is frozen is still present, and then CTRL+ALT+DELETE to remove the other window. Then it runs. Although, I would like to find a better solution in the future.

After 10 min the original frozen version works

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. If you delete a file that is found in the tab of RStudio. You need to wait 5-10 min until it unfreezes and then delete those tabs from RStudio.

Comment: IMHO it should not take that much time to react to deleted files. 
Are you experiencing this on network or local drives? If it is local drives I would open an issue/ticket at RStudio github.      
If these files are on network shares (especially on Windows) this could be related to the boost issues RStudio started showing since version 1.2.5033, where there is already an active issue being tracked, which they mentioned to try to tackle starting with their boost updates planned for vers. 1.5.x.